# page does not scroll

Tags: html, css

[image][image]I have this issue with my CSS where I have lots of content in my HTML but in my browser, in the responsive version it won't scroll anymore, in other words, it stops when there is more content to display. How can I prevent that from occurring? It's been happening for quite some time now. Here is my HTML and CSS code I will add the full code.
p.s. what I mean is that in the developer tools in chrome in order to view the website on different devices it stops in the about section it does not show my javascript skills.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

header .logo-link {
}

header .logo-link .logo-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

header .box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header .box .line-1,
.line-2,
.line-3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

nav .ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .ul .li {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav .ul li .li-a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.landing-page {
  background-color: #111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-page .title {
  margin: 0 0 20px 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.landing-page .name {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.landing-page h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.landing-page .mission {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20 0 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.landing-page .check-out {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#about {
  background-color: #111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#about .bar .skill,
p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#about .bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#about .bar .skill {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#about .bar p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">

        <a href="index.html" class="logo-link"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo-img"></a>
    
        <div class="box">
            <div class="line-1"></div>
            <div class="line-2"></div>
            <div class="line-3"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
        <nav class="nav">
            
            <ul class="ul">
                <li class="li"><a href="#about" class="li-a">About</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a href="" class="li-a">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a href="" class="li-a">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
<section class="landing-page">

    <h1 class="title">Hello world! My name is</h1>
    <h2 class="name"> Jorge Artaza. </h2>
    <h3>I am a Full Stack Developer</h3>
    <p class="mission">My mission is to develop lightning fast website, apps, games, and software that are user friendly.</p>
<p class="check-out">Check out my <br> Portfolio  <span>&#9660;</span></p>
</section>
<section id="about">
    <div class="img-about">
        <img src="" alt="">
<h2>Who am I?</h2>
<p>I am a self taught developer. My interest started at a young age and started to create from that point onward. When I am not developing I am working out or relaxing.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="my-skills">My Skills</p>
<div class="bar">
<div class="skill ">
    <p>HTML</p>
    80%
</div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div class="skill">
        <p>CSS</p>
        80%
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="skill js">
            <p>JavaScript</p>
            70%
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
   
</body>
```

Comment: Would you please share the `head` tag of the html please? Also if you can, would you send a screenshot of how it looks like to explain what you want to end up with? (don't think I understood properly, sorry)

Comment: I didn't see nothing wrong with your code. Just some recomendations, like in the global style(*) add padding: 0px and margin: 0px. And be careful with float, i would recomend use the flex box. So, do what Luka Cerutti said, and maybe we can help you, better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you need to put that in the head, for the site adjust for mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

If you want know more: [Meta viewport - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Also, i will recomend you make some changes on your code:

1 - Remove the heights 100vh and put a fix hight for you components, like 500px, 400px. Examples: `height: 300px;`;

2 - Your code is like a puzzle, put a background-color in your body, not in the components, if you want that the entire page has a black background-color;

3 - Put the sections inside of a main(father element), with that you can use the flex box for adjust your code;

4 - There is on Youtube some great videos about do a better header, i realy don't like this float:righ, because it can bring some problems for you code, like messing the positions of the others elements;

6 - Use the media queries for a better display on the mobile devices, as well - [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) | [Media Queries - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Exemple about the sections:

```
 <main class="main"> 
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
    </main>
```

I will recomend this video about the header, because is the only i have watched in english, but you can have an idea: [Header video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwWHL3RyQgk)

Comment: recommending youtube video is not a solution and he already has the meta tag you mentioned. His problem is adding scroll and height in vh or px shouldn't matter but can be suggested on as good practices